# Is it possible to add og tags to url generated by goo.gl url shortner

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, google-url-shortener, goo.gl

We are using [goo.gl URL shortner](http://goo.gl) to shorten the links.

Is there a way to add [open graph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) to show the rich links for the URL on share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goo.gl offered no way to set OGM tags, and the service has been shut down since March 19, 2019. In their [blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html) about the shut down they recommend Firebase.

Until the 25th of August 2023, Google offered ["dynamic links"](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/) on the Firebase dashboard. This was another similar service that allowed you to set a title, image and description like in this picture: [FDL example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZaku.png). Google took care of setting the correct OGM tags. A link would have looked like `https://something.page.link/something`, in which you can customize both somethings.

There are several other services that let you set Open Graph Meta Tags (some call it "custom branding"). As long as Google Search isn't deprecated I suggest using it to find one.

Comment: Firebase Dynamic links deprecated https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq?hl=en&authuser=0#how_long_will_i_have_to_migrate

Comment: @HarikrishnanR thanks, updated (even though the question is outdated anyway)